# Guys, How can I use google geocode api to calculate euclidean distance?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-api

I'm really struggling. It's a challenge that I am supposed to receive two or more adressess as parameters.

Then I should solve their geolocation using [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

With those informations, I should then use euclidean distance and then apply in all address combinations.

Then return the calculated distances between all addresses and point the closer ones and the farthest ones.

```
const { Client } = require('@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js')

const client = new Client({});

function calculaRota(enderecos) {

    client.geocode({params: {
        address: ``,
        key: "lol"
        
    }}).then((response)=> {console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location)}).catch(console.log)

}
```

That's my progress so far, but I'm struggling really hard. Even their documentation is a little blurry to me to understand. Thanks in advance :)

Obs.: I changed the key for obvious reasons. But it works and I am able to access. But I can't see how I can 'solve the challenge.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance

Comment: You may want to make use of [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview) to calculate the distance between the points. If you pass an address, the service geocodes the string and converts it to a latitude/longitude coordinate to calculate distance.